# Civirules send email

Tags: email, civirules

Hopefully I am just missing something.
I use CiviCRM Version 5.18.4 for WordPress, and I am not a programmer.

I read about CiviRules, and in the documentation, (https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/basic-example-immediate-processing/) the very first,simplest, most basic rule demonstrated uses the action "Send email".  So I install CiviRules, and try to do just that.  Get to "List of actions..." and no "Send email."

Suddenly, I have to be a developer, to ADD the "Send email" action?  And when I look for help here I am led into a maze of suggestions about mgd.php files and adding hook directories and editing tables of the CiviCRM database.

Hey, I just want to send an email to folks when they sign up as contacts.  Do I really need to reinvent this?  Thanks for helping me understand.

Answer (score 7):

You need to also install another extension which is mentioned lower down on the introduction page: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/#other-useful-extensions-and-modules

You need the Email API: https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Scheduled reminders may also be an option without having to use CiviRules?